# HTTPS communication using NodeJS TLS socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, http, https

I want to communicate with a web server from NodeJS. This is what I tried:

```js
let tls = require("tls");
(async function() {
    let socket = tls.connect(443, "google.com", {servername: "google.com"});
    socket.on("OCSPResponse", function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    socket.write(`GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com`);
})();
```

There's no output. I'm expecting to use a similar technique with HTTP servers too using `net` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let tls = require("tls");
(async function() {
    let socket = tls.connect(443, "google.com", {servername: "google.com"});
    socket.on("data", function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    socket.write(`GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.google.com\n\n`);
})();
```